# Docker ogr2ogr & ogrinfo .shp shapefile "Unable to open datasource"

Tags: gdal, ogr, docker, ogrinfo

I am using current [gdal docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/osgeo/gdal/ubuntu-full-3.4.1/images/sha256-f1e71ecedbd02af8c8585728a31ef86fd0269d26902afd12409842a2b377cc95?context=explore) `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.4.1` to display metadata from a shapefile.
After multiple failed attempts of failed installation of GDAL 3.4 on Ubuntu 20.10 I am now using the docker version.

`ogr2ogr` has the same problem, **ogrinfo** failes with the following;

```
❯ docker run osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.4.1 ogrinfo -al myShapefile.shp
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `myShapefile.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRIC
  -> FITS
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> PDS4
  -> VICAR
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> PDF
  -> MBTiles
  -> BAG
  -> EEDA
  -> OGCAPI
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> LVBAG
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GeoJSONSeq
  -> ESRIJSON
  -> TopoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> OGR_DODS
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> MDB
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGR_OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> DXF
  -> CAD
  -> FlatGeobuf
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> WFS
  -> OAPIF
  -> SOSI
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Cloudant
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> Elasticsearch
  -> Walk
  -> Carto
  -> AmigoCloud
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> JML
  -> PLSCENES
  -> CSW
  -> MongoDBv3
  -> VDV
  -> GMLAS
  -> MVT
  -> NGW
  -> MapML
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> HTTP
```

The file is of course present, valid and not read protected. Running with sudo makes no difference. Also specifying a full-path does nothing.

Comment: Are the other "files" of the shapefile also available?

Comment: Yes, all of them - 7 in total. Maybe docker can't read/mount my filesystem?

Comment: Ohh stupid me. Of course you need to *mount* your dir to the docker container, otherwise it won't be available. Use flag `-v yourDataDir:DataDirOnContainer` when running `docker run`.

I will post a full answer tomorrow.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 went end-of-life in July 2021, I'm not surprised you had trouble installing something.  Docker is way overkill to get GDAL working, conda envs are simpler.

Comment: Ah damn. Ok, I will have a try with that.

Answer (score 3):

#### Mount your directory to the docker container

...Of course you need to do that. Otherwise the docker container won't contain any contents and the file `myShapefile.shp` is just not present and the command fails.

Use the `-v` flag to mount a [local directory]:[container directory].
Full command;

```
docker run --rm -v /home/user/data:/data osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.4.1 ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON /data/myShapefile.geojson /data/myShapefile.shp
```

Also see the [Docs - Start a container with a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume)

When done your **current user probably won't have permissions** to access the produced file as it was created by the docker-user.

To **change the file owner** use `sudo chown [your username] [file.shp]`

To **give your user read & write permissions** use `sudo chmod +644 [file.shp]`